# Who was the girl with Kyle Reese in the Terminator?

Tags: character-identification, the-terminator, the-terminator-series

When Kyle Reese was in a car hearing the radio near a construction field, he was dreaming about the future. He was running alongside a girl who was hit by a machine, is this woman Star?

Comment: When Sarah Connor asked Reese if there was a girl in the future he was close to, he looks away with downcast eyes. I always assumed Reese was thinking of Ferro, remembering her death, and trying to forget the pain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel)) names her as **Corporal Ferro**. In the film she's played by Jean Malahni who was Linda Hamilton's stunt double.

> He glanced over his shoulder at the surviving member of his twelve-man
>   squad; Corporal Ferro, a grim, gaunt, female sapper. Fifteen last
>   Tuesday and armed to the fucking teeth. She was staying close to
>   Reese, anchored to her squad leader like a shadow.
>
> ...
>
> As Reese was dropping back behind the wall, he saw Ferro struggling to
>   keep her balance, slipping on the loose concrete fragments in the
>   shadow of the wall. She was still holding the mine, and its timer was
>   running down. “Throw it!” Reese shouted. But she couldn’t unless she
>   jumped on the wall, exposing herself, and the H-K was already swinging
>   around.
>
> She had fucked up. Reese and Ferro stared into each other’s eyes. Then
>   she jumped and threw. She was halfway back down when the searching
>   power bolt punched into her torso. No scream. She went away in a cloud
>   of pink mist.

Purely as an aside, James Cameron evidently liked the name so much that he [recycled it into another of his films](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Colette_Ferro).

---

The [original script](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Terminator.pdf) doesn't name her (she's just "GIRL") so the name may have been an invention of the author of the novelisation or at Cameron's suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Her name is CPL Ferro. You can learn more about her in the recent DLC for Terminator: Resistance. The DLC goes further into the future war and answers a lot of hanging threads and questions about the future scenes in the first two films. IDK if it's canon, but it sure seems like it is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. That name was already submitted in [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/159367/122024) over four years ago though. You have added some additional evidence, but it might've been better to post that as a comment beneath Valorum's answer, rather than as a separate answer in itself. In order to post comments in threads you didn't start yourself, you need to earn a little more [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege.

Comment: Games are very rarely canon to the films, due to the large number of people who'll see the films but never even hear of the games, let alone play them. The same goes for comics and novels.

Comment: @Lincoln Pascual, great info, Im not too much into games, but its a nice an interesitng data, since she seems to be a underrated character because she is a partner of Kyle. Thanks for your answer!!!

Answer (score -1):

I think it may well be Star because I read a trvia in Salvation that it is her in the war flashback

Comment: Where did you read this trivia?